# play framework : rest api creation issue : cannot find symbol symbol: class ObjectNode

Tags: java, rest, playframework

I'm using play framework to create REST api following this documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions#Serving-a-JSON-response

Controller Code snippet:

```
public Result sayHello() {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("exampleField1", "foobar");
    result.put("exampleField2", "Hello world!");
    return ok(result);
}
```

Routes entry:

```
GET     /response-json                  controllers.Application.getJSONResponse
```

Error which I am getting while serving this: "**cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ObjectNode
  location: class controllers.Application**"

Let me know where i'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might just be missing a few imports in your Controller (the examples in the docs do not show all the details).

So your Controller might look something like this - note the imports:-

```
package controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result sayHello() {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("exampleField1", "foobar");
        result.put("exampleField2", "Hello world!");
        return ok(result);
    }
}
```

Also, note that your routes entry needs to be:-

```
GET     /response-json          controllers.Application.sayHello
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps solved this issue:

- Addded this import "import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;"(As mentioned here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaJsonRequests)
- For using above, downloaded jar from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall199jar.htm
- Now I was getting one more issue: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be converted to org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode"
- For solving above changed the above import to "import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;"

Using above steps helped me get it working !!